# what is the SQL equivalent of this mongoose query

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, mongoose

```
ProjectModel.find({projectName: 'name'}).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(5).exec( 
    function(err, projects) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Just trying to learn whats this query is doing. i believe it is searching for `viewCount` in a descending order and the result is limited to 5.

Comment: It's searching for projects that have projectName `'name'`, sorting them by viewCount and limits it to 5 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from project where projectName = 'name' order by viewCount desc limit 5
```

Comment: what does the `***` means? and where does `projectName : "name"` being factored in this SQL query?

Comment: 'name' is the value that the query is looking to find in the projectName column

Answer (score 0):

Searching on projectName where projectName equals 'name', then sorting descending on viewCount, then limiting to 5 records in the result.  so yea, you got it mostly correct.

I'm not sure if mongoose's find is equals, or like/contains; probably equals by default.  Check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name from projects order By viewCount LIMIT 5
```

Comment: what if i want to do `select _id from projects order by viewCount LIMIT 5` what would be mongoose query be like?